# Docker service start after server restart

Tags: ubuntu, docker, service, rabbitmq

I'm struggling with dockers (17) on Ubuntu(14). I have to run rabbitMQ on a couple of machines using docker technology. I managed to do that on one of them using

```
sudo docker service create -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=user -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=password rabbitmq:3-management
```

but i encounter a problem on others. When i run Rabbit as a docker service everything is OK, but the problem starts after restarting the machine. After server reboot the docker is started automaticaly- i run

```
sudo docker service list
sudo docker ps
```

to check that. But when I want to connect to the rabbitServer using the browser nothing happens. When i use curl or wget inside the servier it waits for the response and nothing happens. when i run

```
sudo service docker restart
```

then everything starts to work like it should. the ports are open all the time, and the info is saved so after restart i dont have to reopen them. One of the machines does not have this problem and everything works even after restart

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's weird and i still don't know why this works. After I rebooted the machine, then I restarted docker service as well and after that i saved again the ipconfig persistent configuration without adding anything to the rules- it started working on all of the machines

Answer (score 9):

I believe it is because your docker daemon and / or containers doesn't start when you reboot the machine. To achieve that you should do something as follows:

```
sudo systemctl enable docker
```

This should start the Docker daemon after you reboot the host. Then what you will have to do is when you run the service is to pass

```
--restart-condition:any
```

Which should start your containers in case or a system failure or reboot in this case.

Comment: after restart when i run **sudo docker service list** the rabbit server is in the result, also when i run **sudo docker ps** the rabbit is there too. doesn't  it mean the the deamon is running after server restart?

Comment: @TajnosAgentos well I believe if after rebooting and once you run those commands then yes the docker daemon has successfully started as well as the rabbit container(s).

Comment: `docker ps` automatically starts the docker service. @sergiu on https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#configure-docker-to-start-on-boot they recommend `sudo systemctl enable docker.service` and `sudo systemctl enable containerd.service`. Could you explain the difference?

Comment: @velop the differences between those 2 is that: containerd is a kernel abstraction which allows other software projects to use it and run containers, whereas Docker is a high level interface that allows you to build images and run containers from the terminal. Docker uses containerd as the container runtime.